# Calculating means and standard errors for time data

Tags: r, time, mean, standard-error

Is there a way to calculate means and standard error for time duration data? I have tried to work through similar fixes on this site but have not been successful.

The data needs to be grouped by "Site" and "Treatment".

I'd like to be able to calculate the mean and standard error of "HH.MM.SS' for each "Treatment" according to each "Site".

```
    names(Socials)
    [1] "Site"      "Date"      "Treatment" "Block"     "HH.MM.SS"  "Max.N"
```

A sample of the data is below (one of two sites):

```
    Site       Date Treatment Block             HH.MM.SS Max.N
    MH 2018-10-06         C     1     2020-07-05 00:08:05           9
    MH 2018-10-08         D     1     2020-07-05 00:12:56           6
    MH 2018-10-07         V     1     2020-07-05 00:57:52           4
    MH 2018-10-05     V + D     1     2020-07-05 00:53:14           4
    MH 2018-10-12         C     2     2020-07-05 00:03:57           7
    MH 2018-10-10         D     2     2020-07-05 00:21:34           2
    MH 2018-10-11         V     2     2020-07-05 01:10:24           4
    MH 2018-10-09     V + D     2     2020-07-05 01:15:17           6
    MH 2018-10-15         C     3     2020-07-05 00:08:44           1
    MH 2018-10-13         D     3     2020-07-05 00:58:22          23
    MH 2018-10-14         V     3     2020-07-05 00:00:07           3
    MH 2018-10-16     V + D     3     2020-07-05 01:09:12           4


    # CreatePOSIXct time objects for date.
    Socials$Date <- as.POSIXct(Socials$Date, format = "%d/%m/%y")

    # CreatePOSIXct time objects for the total time duration for each treatment
    Socials$HH.MM.SS <- as.POSIXct(Socials$HH.MM.SS, format = "%H:%M:%OS")
```

I have not provided all the data here, so the data could be subset, as per the below, to produce a working  example

```
   #Subset Data - split sites MH and GI 
    MH.data <- subset(Socials, Site == 'MH')
    GI.data <- subset(Socials, Site == 'GI')

    ##### Calculate summary statistics for Observations ######
    library(data.table) 
    library(plotrix)

    df1 = data.table(Socials)

    df1_output = df1[, .("HH.MM.SS" = mean(HH.MM.SS), 
                   "std" = std.error(Treatment)), 
               by = c("Site", "Treatment")]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. I hope the information provided here is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do it normally. This just worked for me:

```
> x=c(as.Date("2018-10-06"), as.Date("2018-11-06"), as.Date("2018-12-06"))
> mean(x)
[1] "2018-11-05"
> sd(x)
[1] 30.50137
> std.error(x)
[1] 17.60997
```

Comment: Great, thank you @DerekFulton. I apprecaite your assistance.

Comment: Although, I need to calculate time, not date. I will try and use this basic formula to calculate the values to time. Given that I have quite a bit of data to process and graphs to produce, it would be helpful to have a formula to apply to all treatments/sites. I'll persevere appreciate your assistance.